# sed replace string with numbers special characters

Tags: bash, sed, grep

i want to replace

```
4328"  +  base64_encode\("\x86\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x25\x07\x2E\x01\x02\x03\x04\xBB\x01\x62\x1A\x01\x01
```

with

```
4321\x38\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93
```

tried lots of option nothing work out the last i tried is

```
sed -i 's/4328["]  +  base64_encode[(]"\x86\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x25\x07\x2E\x01\x02\x03\x04\xBB\x01\x62\x1A\x01\x01/"4321\x38\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93"/g' *.utt
```

Comment: This works `sed 's/4328"  +  base64_encode\\("\\x86\\x01/4321\\x38\\x80/'`. I omitted some of the repeating parts of your strings.

Comment: Since there is a long sequence of strings of the form `\x..`, you can abbreviate the string you want to replace, and write (using extended regex): `sed -r 's/4328"  \+  base64_encode\\\("(\\x..)+/4321\\x38\\x80/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, tested with shown samples only.

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+\".*\x[0-9]+/321\\x38\\x80\\x81\\x8\\x83\\x84\\x85\\x86\\x87\\x88\\x89\\x8A\\x8B\\x8C\\x8D\\x8E\\x8F\\x90\\x91\\x92\\x93/g'  Input_file
```

Let's say we have following Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
singh is king bla bla 4328"  +  base64_encode\("\x86\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x25\x07\x2E\x01\x02\x03\x04\xBB\x01\x62\x1A\x01\x01
```

Now after running code we will get following output.

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+\".*\x[0-9]+/321\\x38\\x80\\x81\\x8\\x83\\x84\\x85\\x86\\x87\\x88\\x89\\x8A\\x8B\\x8C\\x8D\\x8E\\x8F\\x90\\x91\\x92\\x93/g'  Input_file
singh is king bla bla 321\x38\x80\x81\x8\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8A\x8B\x8C\x8D\x8E\x8F\x90\x91\x92\x93
```

Comment: thanks when i run shows  the changed value but when i again check the value in file  it is same .i have to do this for all the files in a folder.

Comment: If you want to save output into input_file itself use `se -i` option in solution. Try it first for 1 file if happy then only pass all files to command.

Comment: Also by seeing your profile came to know that you never select any answer as correct one. Give it sometime when you see enough answers in post select anyone of them as correct one too.

Comment: thanks sed -i.bak  -E 's/[4328]+\".*\x[0-9]+/4321\\x38\\x80\\x81\\x8\\x83\\x84\\x85\\x86\\x87\\x88\\x89\\x8A\\x8B\\x8C\\x8D\\x8E\\x8F\\x90\\x91\\x92\\x93/g'

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 not really when i get my answer I have always selected the correct answer .after trying it